# Showing attachments in popups using Arcade with ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments, arcade

I'm trying to follow the instructions in [Show Attachments in Pop-ups with Arcade Expressions](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-blog/show-attachments-in-pop-ups-with-arcade/ba-p/890588)

I want to show the first attachment in a popup in ArcGIS Online and to do that I need to obtain the first attachment ID using this Arcade expression:

> return First(Attachments($feature)).ID

The error I get is this:

> Execution Error:Runtime Error: Cannot call member method on null. ID

My attachments are associated with a layer that I cannot share publicly. Unlike the video there is a very long Token ID that runs after the attachments ID. Here's a small section of what I'm looking at:

> ........./FeatureServer/0/6/attachments/52?token=s9r_RuK9ix5DTY-lcrYXVOJ9GEvJWG.......

How do I write an Arcade expression to obtain the first Attachment ID on a private feature layer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Your layer needs to be made public.](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-blog/show-attachments-in-pop-ups-with-arcade/ba-p/890588#:%7E:text=The%20layer%20needs%20to%20be%20public%20to%20access%20attachments.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.